# Rounding problems inside InputField

Tags: dynamic, machine-precision, inputfield

**The community needs to determine if this is behavior is a bug or not. – *Mr.Wizard***

---

Consider the following `InputField`

```
InputField[Dynamic[h2,
  If[# === Null, h2 = h2, h2 = Round[#, 0.001]] &], Number]
```

The purpose of the second argument of Dynamic is to avoid someone entering a value with more than 3 decimal places (or emptying the field after some value has been assigned).

For example, entering 0.4691 immediately reassigns the `InputField` to 0.469.

The problem is that entering the number 0.468 renders 0.4680000000000001. I imagine it’s something to do with the representation of 0.468 in binary, etc.

How can I avoid this after rounding action?

**EDIT:**

After some more testings, I see that it is the `Number` part that is causing the problem.

This works "badly":

```
InputField[Dynamic[h2], Number]
```

This works OK:

```
InputField[Dynamic[h2]]
```

[image]

If you do `Do[h2 = i; Pause[0.1], {i, 0.04, 0.08, 0.001}]`, you can get a good picture of the problem:

[image]

How can I avoid this `Number` side effect?

Comment: Defining h2 in a DynamicModule seems to do the trick, but I don't know if it serves your use, and have no idea why

Comment: @Rojo I don't think it would serve my use, since I'm defining this variable at the notebook level (I'm even using it inside NotebookDynamicExpression)

Comment: @Timo I'm on mma 8.0.4 on Windows XP. But I'm glad to know it works fine on other platforms, since it does look like a bug...

Comment: Works OK in WinXP Mma 8.0.0

Comment: Since this hasn't been fixed (as of 10.3.0), and it has a different behaviour on other platforms, should this be tagged as Bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work for me, is it what you need?

```
InputField[Dynamic[h2, If[NumericQ[#], h2 = Round[#, 0.001], h2 = h2] &]]
```

Comment: Your work around works fine for my specific case, but since it is not a solution for the "bug", since it doesn't cover all the functionality of Number (e.g. assign h2="a" from outside the InputField). I'll wait a little longer to see if there are other solutions (before validating one)...

Answer (score 5):

Since the type `Number` won't allow formatted numbers to be displayed, set the accuracy (or precision) of the displayed value to control the number of digits:

```
InputField[Dynamic[If[h2 == 0, 0., SetAccuracy[h2, 4]], (h2 = Round[#, 0.001]) &], Number]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullForm[h2]
(*  0.468`  *)
```

It does have the disadvantage that numbers like `0.12` will be displayed as `0.120`. A more complicated program could be written to handle that, if desired.