# How to format dynamic InputField value using NumberForm?

Tags: dynamic, formatting

Background: I want all numbers in `InputField`'s displayed as `NumberForm[num,2]`;

Now, consider the following the snippet of code:

```
 latsy = 1.1;
 latparshx = 32;
 piet = NumberForm[latsy*Tan[latparshx*Pi/180], 2];
 InputField[Dynamic[piet], FieldSize -> 3]
```

This code produces an inputfield with a number between double quotes, which is not what I expected. I basically want 0.69 displayed.

**Question: How can I ( what is the best way to ) control the display format of a number in an InputField ?**

EDIT: The InputField resizes itself on the Panel it is positioned on and thus messes up the other GUI elements.

Comment: Related: [Rounding problems inside InputField](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/rounding-problems-inside-inputfield)

Comment: Maybe you could define a new style with options like `PrintPrecision -> 2`, and then use `InputField[piet, Number, BaseStyle -> {"MyStyle"}]` (removing the `NumberForm` wrapper from `piet`). This is the most I could dig up from the Documentation, and since I don't know how to define styles from a notebook, I'm stuck here.

Comment: What would happen if I enter 0.123?  Would the variable be set to 0.12 or 0.123?  If it is set to 0.123 and displayed as 0.12 in the InputField, but then I click in the InputField again and press enter, will that change the value to 0.12?

Comment: Me too, but I can dig into it. I am not keen on changing Notebook options though. I am surprised that this turns out to be so awkward.

Comment: @Szabolcs to .123 and display as .12, And yes.

Comment: @ndroock1 You didn't reply my second question: what happens if I click in the InputField displaying 0.12 and press enter?  Will it truncate the value to 0.12?  If not, how can it tell that it shouldn't?  (Maybe `Interpretation`.)

Comment: The thing is that the data is calculated elsewhere. The actual inputfield will not be used, it's just an escape if the calculations aren't precise enough or not possible.

Comment: I did :-). By adding "And yes.". @Szabolcs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Round` to control the representation.

```
latsy = 1.1;
latparshx = 32;
piet = Round[latsy*Tan[latparshx*Pi/180], 0.01];
InputField[Dynamic[piet], FieldSize -> 3]
```

EDIT:
If rounding is desirable limiting the size of the input field is an option

```
latsy = 1.1;
latparshx = 32;
piet = latsy*Tan[latparshx*Pi/180];
InputField[Dynamic[piet], Number, FieldSize -> {3, 1},ContinuousAction -> True]
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should use two variables, one for presentation and one for further calculations? Is that how it is done? How you do it? ( Rounding the data in the app I work on is not acceptable, would lose too much precision. )

Comment: @ndroock1 Two variables could be a possibility, but seems unpleasant as a solution. I've added another option which limits the displayed size of the input field. But it just masks the remaining digits of the number, which is confusing if you intend users to edit it.

Comment: The 'editing' is done via controls mostly. The inputfield is a last resort fine-tuning option, so yes it's confusing but better than maintaining two sets of vars in the program. I'll see how it works.

Comment: The \ sign shows if the field is cut off, which is good.

Comment: @ndroock1 I'm pleased that the characteristics help in your context :)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is have your stuff displayed without the string characters then just do this -- i.e. keeping the code you have already:

```
latsy = 1.1;
latparshx = 32;
piet = Style[NumberForm[latsy*Tan[latparshx*Pi/180], 2], 
   ShowStringCharacters -> False
   ];

InputField[Dynamic[piet], FieldSize -> 3]
```

But there are other things you could also do, e.g. István Zachar mentioned `PrintPrecision`:

```
latsy = 1.1;
latparshx = 32;
piet = 0.12345678;

Style[
 InputField[Dynamic[piet], FieldSize -> 3],
 PrintPrecision -> 2
 ]
```

and so on.