# How to prevent Round with hidden fractions

Tags: numerics

I found a strange behavior in Round. If we try:

```
ToString[Round[4.811, 0.01], InputForm]
```

we get:

> 4.8100000000000005

When I expected

> 4.81

In order to get what I need, we can do something like (@Pickett and my suggestions):

```
N@FromDigits@RealDigits@Round[4.811, 0.01]
```

or

```
Internal`StringToDouble@ToString@Round[4.811, 0.01]
```

There is a simpler solution for this?

**Speed teste**

```
range=Range[1,1000,0.01];
(t1=N@FromDigits@RealDigits@Round[#,0.01]&/@range)//AbsoluteTiming//First
(t2=Internal`StringToDouble@ToString@Round[#,0.01]&/@range)//AbsoluteTiming//First
```

> 0.999
>
> 0.460

**Update**

Important note. @BobHanlon solution stop to work for lists with more than 99 elements. Mathematica compiles de expression `N@Round[#,1/100]&/@list`, and the unwanted behavior came back. To prevent that, I used Listable `Round` attribute.

Similar question: [Rounding problems inside InputField](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4685)

Comment: Related: [(7871)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7871/121), [(55292)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55292/121),

Comment: This saved my day! Thank you, Murta

Answer (score 3):

`myround` is undefined. I assume that you mean `Round`.

```
ToString[Round[4.811, 0.01]]
```

> "4.81"

```
ToString[Round[4.811, .01 // Rationalize] // N, InputForm]
```

> "4.81"

Comment: Yes, corrected `myround` to round. N@Round[4.811, 1/100] is much faster. tks +1

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you should be using a number formatting function, e.g. [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html), for the kind of control you are apparently after.

For `Round` and `ToString` only you could use [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm.html):

```
ToString[Round[4.811, 0.01], OutputForm]
```

> ```
> "4.81"
> ```

Which is the default and therefore equivalent to this on an unmodified installation:

```
ToString @ Round[4.811, 0.01]
```

---

I am not sure how to interpret your comment but addressing one possible reading please consider:

```
a = Round[4.811, 0.01];
b = N @ FromDigits @ RealDigits @ Round[4.811, 0.01];

ToString[{a, b}, InputForm]

RealDigits[{a, b}]
```

> ```
> "{4.8100000000000005, 4.81}"
>
> {{{4, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 1},
>  {{4, 8, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9}, 1}}
> ```

Although `b` happens to print as you desire you can see that its decimal conversion (with `RealDigits`) is not as "good" as the simple `Round` result.  Neither number is accurate because you cannot represent 481/100 as a machine precision binary number:

```
RealDigits[481/100, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}}, 3}
> ```

Therefore this is unlikely to be a desirable *numeric* operation, returning us again to the domain of output formatting.  What exactly is your intention?

Comment: Tks @Mr.Wizard, but I need it as numbers. Now I'm using N@Round[4.811, 1/100]. I have some problems with automatic compilation, but now it's ok. OutputForm has problems with big numbers, and InputForm works just nice.

Comment: @Murta Please see my addendum.

Comment: I use it to create a SQL insert statement, where numbers are rounded to prevent unnecessary file size. My  insert get much more fast with this rounded "bulk" mechanist. I'll post a question/answer showing how it works, it's interesting to be shared.