# Workaround of non-integer indexed objects?

Tags: functions, precision-and-accuracy, index

When using indexed object, I found the behavior of value 0.7 as the index quite strange, then did the following test.

[image]

The first output cell was executed directly as the second input cell.

Have not found other values with the same issue.

---

Edit: an example where non-int indexing is used in my intuitive but trouble-causing way.

```
 SimuBody[p1_, p2_] := Table[N@Sin[p1 x], {x, 1, p2, 1}]
 Table[p2 = 15; f[p1, p2] = SimuBody[p1, p2], {p1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.1}];
 Table[p2 = 12; 
 f[p1, p2] = SimuBody[p1, p2], {p1, {2.2, 0.001, -\[Pi], 3.3}}];
 Table[p2 = 5; f[p1, p2] = SimuBody[p1, p2], {p1, {7, 3.4}}];
 g[a_Symbol] := 
 DownValues[a] /. (HoldPattern[_[_[x__]]] :> z_) :> {{x}, z}
 ftab = g[f];
 ListPointPlot3D[
 Transpose@{ftab[[All, 1, 1]], ftab[[All, 1, 2]], ftab[[All, 2, 1]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Bottom]
 f[0.7, 15]
```

I started using this non-int indexing method after reading [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html), where the index does not even have to be a number. So I assumed using non-integer should be ok.

Comment: Moral lesson: do not use inexact numbers for indexing. (I'm sure this is a dupe, but I can't find the earlier thread.)

Comment: @J.M. closely related: [65298](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65298/5478)

Comment: Regardless of the subtleties of floating point arithmetic that cause this, I think this is a classic case of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).  What were you hoping to achieve by putting a non-integer number in `Indexed`?

Comment: @J.M. But I need a dynamical container for elements at a particular time. Is there any way to do so without inexact indexing?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to explain your application further, and maybe we can reopen this.

Comment: @Szabolcs For instance, my simulation has a non-int parameter `k` and returns `list1`. I use an indexed object `f[k]` to map the resulting 'list1'. This mapping is intuitive to me, e.g. I can use `ListPlot` to plot certain element in `f[k]` against all the `k`s I have used in simulation. The thing is, I do not know in advance how many `k` I will need before getting the simulation reuslt, so it is awkward to use a fixed-sized list to store the data of `k` and `list1`. I will be glad if you can offer reference to a elegant method.

Comment: @J.M. Ok. Let me work out a concrete example.

Comment: When you said "indexed object", I thought you meant `Indexed`.  Now I see what you mean.  I think using the term "indexing" here may be confusing to some.  I agree with J.M., please edit the post and explain what you said in your comment, then also show how the problem with comparing floating point numbers comes up.  The simplest solution is to avoid this sort of comparison, but there may be other ways too (e.g. `Nearest` for binary search, etc.)  My answer would depend on how exactly you end up comparing two floating point numbers which *look* the same but aren't really the same.

Comment: I just saw your update.  In that example, it looks like you are comparing `0.7` that you typed by hand to `0.7` that was generated by `Table`.  Is this the only situation where the problem comes up?  I would suggest trying to always work with the exact parameters (`p1`, `p2` values) that were generated by/for your simulation.  Avoid using values you type by hand.  When you want to find a value that you *know* exists, you can use `Nearest` to extract it from an existing list of `p1`-values. To make it easier to handle these, I suggest using `Association` instead of `DownValues`.

Comment: I.e. for a one-parameter case, you'd have a `results` association which has elements of the form `p1 -> res`.  You *know* based on something that it should have the key 0.7.  But do not extract it as `results[0.7]`.  Instead use something like `results[ Nearest[Keys[results], 0.7] ]`.  Performance shouldn't matter since you typed this by hand anyway.

Comment: Try indexing with strings; e.g., `f["0.7"] = 1`

Comment: @Szabolcs Hmm. `Association` looks great!