# Mod[1.2, 0.2] is not equal to zero

Tags: numerics, number-representation, modular-arithmetic

Why doesn't the following expression evaluate to zero?

```
In[1]:=Mod[1.2, 0.2]
Out[1]=0.2
```

Edit:

This is what I wanted to do:

```
xgrid = Table[{i,If[Mod[i, 0.2] == 0 , GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.8]]}, {i, 0, 1.5, 0.05}]
```

I haven't programmed in a while so I forgot this happens. It was probably an error due to floating point arithmetic (0.2 cannot be fully represented by binary digits) so this was my solution:

```
xgrid = Table[{i*0.05, If[Mod[i, 4] == 0 , GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.8]]}, {i, 0, 30, 1}]
```

This may also be the reason [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24068/22344) solution for plotting minor and major grid lines didn't work for me

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: AFAIK this is a common attribute of floating point arithmetic, and is expected behavior. Note that `Mod[6/5, 1/5]` gives `0`.

Comment: What @DumpsterDoofus said can be seen in this example by looking at the input form of the result. `In[1]:= Mod[1.2, 0.2] // InputForm

Out[1]//InputForm=
0.1999999999999999`

Comment: Thanks, I Guess I'll have to find a workaround with integers

Comment: @PatrickChin Try `Rationalize`.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Documentation states: `The arguments of Mod can be any numeric quantities, not necessarily integers`. So I don't think it is expected.

Comment: Expected or not, it is correct behavior, and for the reason given by @DumpsterDoofus. Machine floats are not in general exactly representable and roundoff error will give rise to this type of behavior, wherein e.g. 1.2-5*.2 is not exactly equal to 0.2, and 1.2-6*.2 is not exactly zero.

Comment: @Kuba: On the contrary, this sort of thing happens all the time. For example, note that in the high-performance scientific computing language Julia, there is a separate built-in function `mod2pi` for modulus under exact 2*pi. From the documentation, "mod2pi(x): This function computes a floating point representation of the modulus after division by numerically exact 2pi, and is therefore not exactly the same as mod(x,2pi), which would compute the modulus of x relative to division by the floating-point number 2pi." This is an unpleasant but unavoidable feature of floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I agree, but documentation should warn about that since MMA is advertised as suited also for people without programming/IT/numeric background.

Comment: @Kuba: Yeah you're right, I feel like it should be listed in the `Possible Issues` section of the `Mod` documentation, but there are no warnings of the behavior listed there. Maybe the OP can suggest it to bug support as a feature request for the documentation?

Comment: @Kuba I answered before seeing your comment.

Answer (score 11):

Already answered in the comments by [DumpsterDoofus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9697/dumpsterdoofus) and [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau), to summarize:

Machine floating point numbers such as 0.2 are not always exactly representable in binary (no terminating expansion in base 2). Thus floating point arithmetic is susceptible to roundoff error and other [accuracy problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). For example, the following are not exactly equal to 0.2 and 0. respectively:

```
1.2 - 5*0.2 // InputForm

(* 0.19999999999999996 *)

1.2 - 6*0.2 // InputForm

(* -2.220446049250313*^-16 *)
```

Such phenomena are not specific to *Mathematica* at all, e.g. Python's `%` and `fmod` operators give the exact same result as `Mod`:

```python
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
\>>> 1.2 % 0.2
0.1999999999999999
\>>> import math
\>>> math.fmod(1.2, 0.2)
0.1999999999999999
```

Comment: +1. This issue also arises in [Rounding problems inside InputField](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/rounding-problems-inside-inputfield) and the duplicates linked to it.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work

```
Mod[Rationalize@1.2, Rationalize@0.2] == 0
```

I also tried with SetAccuracy, but it didn't always work.

"If Your Only Tool Is a Hammer Then Every Problem Looks Like a Nail"
What I mean is that I'm using here a function that is probably quite involved (Rationalize) for a problem that doesn't look complex (although it is complex when you have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that [`QuotientRemainder`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QuotientRemainder.html) has logic to improve handling of this issue, though it's not perfect, and unfortunately your given example is one of the exceptions.

A simple example where it behaves "better" than `Mod`:

```
a = 1.2`;
b = 0.2`;

Mod[10 a, b]
QuotientRemainder[10 a, b]
```

> ```
> 0.2
>
> {60, 0.}
> ```

Ideally we would want all integer multiples of `a` to have a remainder of either zero or `b`.  Let's compare:

```
myMod = QuotientRemainder[#, #2][[All, 2]]&;  (* only for lists *)

Mod[Range[1*^6] a, b]    // Union // Length
myMod[Range[1*^6] a, b]  // Union // Length
```

> ```
> 795632
>
> 35
> ```

So while `Mod` produces nearly 80% "unique" values (according to [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html)) `QuotientRemainder` does so in only a few of the cases tested.