# MemberQ not working?

Tags: numerics, pattern-matching

I'm confused by the following trivial code:

```
{Range[0, 1, .1][[8]]} === {.7}
```

gives `True`

```
MemberQ[{.7}, .7]
```

gives `True`, but

```
MemberQ[{Range[0, 1, .1][[8]]}, .7]
```

gives `False`. Huh? What am I missing?

Comment: `{Range[0, 1, .1][[8]], .7} // InputForm` ought to be enlightening. Moral lesson is that you don't do such pattern matches on inexact numbers.

Comment: @J.M. thanks, I thought it might be a floating point thing, but then I was surprised by the first equality, which I still don't understand

Comment: That would be due to ``Internal`$SameQTolerance`` (or ``Internal`$EqualTolerance`` if you had used `==`). See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626748).

Comment: @J.M. Great, thanks!

Comment: Recommended reading: [(5149)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5149/121), [(5580)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5580/121), [(21711)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21711/121), [(66386)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66386/121), [(86815)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86815/121).  Please take a look at these and tell me if you feel that your question is adequately addressed in these. If so we can mark it as such.