# Dynamic Slider and InputField: some numbers with machine precision display badly

Tags: output-formatting, inputfield, slider

I want to control a value in my program either by a `Slider` or an `InputField`. The following code does what I want in principle:

```
Row[{"Some value", Slider[Dynamic[value], {0, 2, 0.1}], 
InputField[Dynamic[value], Number, ImageSize -> 40]}]
```

When moving the slider, the value should only change in steps of 0.1. However, for some values, the following happens:

[image]

I guess that this is due to machine precision errors or something similar. I don't really care if the value is that little greater than 0.7, that won't disturb my calculations. However, I would like the `InputField` to only show one decimal digit. What would be the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Take a look at these questions and see if the answers to them answer your question: [4685](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4685), [6259](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6259)

Comment: They helped me insofar that i recognized the `number`-attribute to be the problem. I just leave that out now and the problem is gone. It's not the best solution, since I only want numbers as input, but I can live with it!

Comment: Hi Timitry, I added an [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73367) to question 4685.  It should work for your case, too.  E.g., `InputField[Dynamic[If[value == 0, 0., SetAccuracy[value, 2]], (value = #) &], Number, ImageSize -> 40]`.